# Assume $\int^a_b \operatorname{tr}(A(t)B(t))~dt=0$ for any $B$, where $A,B$ are $n \times n$ matrices. Does this imply $A=0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, lie-groups

Assume $\displaystyle\int^a_b  \operatorname{tr}(A(t)B(t))~dt=0$ for any $B$, where $A,B$ are $n \times n$ matrices.

Does this imply $A=0$?

If this is not true, can we add some conditions for $A, B$ to make the proposition true?  For example, add some conditions like $A$ is symmetric, $A$ is skew-symmetric, both $A~\text{and}~B \in SO(n)$, etc.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are matricial functions, aren't they?

Comment: Hint: Set $B(t)=A(t)^T$.

Comment: @MathLover Rather, set $B(t) = A(t)^T$.

Comment: @mechanodroid Thanks.

Comment: You can conclude that $A(t) = 0$ for ae. $t$.

Comment: What is $A(t)$ if $A$ is a matrix? (Even if the question is answered I would still like to know.)

Comment: @DionelJaime A matrix whose coefficients are (sufficiently regular) functions of a parameter $t$, presumably.

Comment: $\langle A, B \rangle := \int_b^a tr(A(t) B^*(t))\,dt$ makes the space of $L^2$ matrix functions into a Hilbert space.

Comment: $\operatorname{tr} (A^TA) = \|A\|_F^2$, the Frobenius norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Math Lover's hint, consider $B(t)$ being $A(t)^\top$. Then check that the integrand $\text{tr}(A(t) A(t)^\top)=\sum_i \sum_j A(t)_{ij}^2$ is nonnegative.

Comment: Or better yet $B=A^\dagger$, so the argument works even for complex matrices.